# Asp.Net Mvc project net compiling in Visual Studio MacOs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-mac

I have an Asp.NET MVC project I have been working on my window machine that I want to migrate to my MacOS machine. The project was build with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25420.01 Update 3 on Windows. I have Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac Version 7.1 (build 1297) installed on my MacBook.

The Error I get when I try to compile on Mac is

> /Users/oluwayomi/Downloads/MisBoard/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.7/build/net45/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props(5,5): Error MSB4174: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be found in the assembly "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.2.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll". (MSB4174) (MisBoard)